# Display aspect ratio item and image in a row in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart, aspect-ratio

Let's say that I want create a *Flutter* app. In my app I want to create a `Row` widget with the following children:

- `AspectRatio(aspectRatio: 1, child: Center(child: Text("I am text!"))`
- `Image.asset("path/to/asset.png")` with unknown aspect ratio

I want to display that `Row` while keeping both aspect ratios intact. How can I do that?

Here is my attempt:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("This is my app")),
      body: Container(
        child: Row(children: [buildItem1(), buildItem2()]),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildItem1() {
    return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 1,
        child: Container(
            color: Colors.red, child: Center(child: Text("This is my text"))));
  }

  Widget buildItem2() {
    return Image.asset("path/to/my/asset.jpg");
  }
}
```

And this is what being displayed:
[image: dart error]

I am trying to figure out a way to automatically shrink the row height such that both items would fit the screen.

If I use a fixed hight like that:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("This is my app")),
      body: Container(
        height: 300,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [buildItem1(), buildItem2()],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
...
```

Than I get the following:

[image: dart better]

Which is better, but I want to fill the entire width of the screen.

Thanks for anyone who can help!

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the error and image you are trying to archive?

Comment: Hey @YeasinSheikh, I added my attempt.

Comment: I want a way to automaticaly shrink the row height such that both items fit the screen

Comment: you like to have image height same as text widget, means image widget height wil depend on text widget height?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, yes.

Comment: Is it necessary to have aspect ratio?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh, yes. I elaborated a little bit more in the problem description to explain exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Expanded` on second widget, that will get the avialable space on row. Also for the image use `fit: BoxFit.cover`(better looks than `width`).

```dart
body: Container(
  height: 300,
  child: Row(
    children: [buildItem1(), Expanded(child: buildItem2())],
  ),
),
```

```dart
  Widget buildItem2() {
    return Image.asset(
      "assets/images/user.png",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    );
  }
```

---

Now if you want full screen, I will prefer

```dart
Row(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Center(
            child: Text("This is my text"),
          )),
    ),
    Expanded(
        child: Image.asset(
      "assets/images/user.png",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    )),
  ],
),
```

Also LayoutBuilder on scaffold's `body` provide more options. Also check `IntrinsicHeight`.